# Send value to function and send back result to initial function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, axios

I have 2 functions and I want to send values back and forth to each other.

```
const higher_fnc = (query_name) => {
  return axios({
    url: GraphQL_Endpoint,
    method: "post",
    headers: headers,
    data: query_name,
  });
};

const func1 = (arg1, arg2) => {
  higher_fnc({
    query: query1,
    variables: {
      id: arg1
    },
  }).then((d) => {
    for (const x of d.data) {
      const arr = [];
      for (const node of x.nodes) {
        const myObj = {};
        if (node.id === "56789") {
          func2(node.internalID);
          arr.push(arg2);
        }
      }
    }
  });
  });
}

const func2 = (val) => {
  higher_fnc({
    query: query1,
    variables: {
      id: val
    },
  }).then((d) => func1("", d.main));
}
```

Basically, I need `func1` to send a value to `func2` and then I need `func2` to send back values to `func1`.

Right now my code is just sending empty strings.

Comment: You have unmatched brackets in the middle function.

Comment: Use `await` to make programming with promises easier.